# Can't get show/hide to repeat on a menu item after first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I am attempting to repeat a show/hide command on a div in a little navigation menu I am creating. I can get the show/hide to work once on all four buttons, but I can't get it to repeat if I were to click the same button three times. It simply adds the active class, but doesn't hide the remaining div's again. I want the action that clicking and unclicking the div has to work every time forever.

JS Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/c3md14jf/

HTML:

```
<div class="mobile-container">
    <div class="mobile-row">
        <a href="#fa">
        <div class="mobile-square">
            <i class="fa fa-globe" style="font-size:48px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <p>
                Foreign Affairs
            </p>
        </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#travel">
        <div class="mobile-square">
            <i class="fa fa-plane" style="font-size:48px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <p>
                Travel
            </p>
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mobile-container">
    <div class="mobile-row">
        <a href="#dev">
        <div class="mobile-square">
            <i class="fa fa-code" style="font-size:48px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <p>
                Development
            </p>
        </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#misc">
        <div class="mobile-square">
            <i class="fa fa-heart" style="font-size:48px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <p>
                Fitness
            </p>
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo|Open+Sans|PT+Sans|Quicksand|Raleway|Ubuntu|Montserrat');

body {
    color: #008fc5;
    background-color: #fff;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin: 0;
}

i {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.mobile-container a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.mobile-row {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.mobile-square {
    width: 49%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 95px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #008fc5;
    text-align:center;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position:relative;
}
.mobile-square p {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.active {
    background-color: #004762;
}
```

JS:

```
var mobileSquare = $(".mobile-square");

mobileSquare.click(function(){
    var activeSquare = $(this);
    activeSquare.toggleClass("active");
    mobileSquare.not(activeSquare).hide();

    activeSquare.click(function(){
        mobileSquare.not(activeSquare).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I only changed the on("click", function(){...}) handler, so that rather than using show/hide i'm using toggle. By doing this, I don't have to have the click handler for the activeclass. I suspect that may have been part of the problem.

```js
var mobileSquare = $(".mobile-square");

mobileSquare.on("click", function(){
 var activeSquare = $(this);
 activeSquare.toggleClass("active");
 mobileSquare.not(activeSquare).toggle();

});
```

```css
/* General Rules */

/* <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo|Open+Sans|PT+Sans|Quicksand|Raleway|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo|Open+Sans|PT+Sans|Quicksand|Raleway|Ubuntu|Montserrat');

body {
 color: #008fc5;
 background-color: #fff;
}

p {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 22px;
 margin: 0;
}

i {
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.mobile-container a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.mobile-row {
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 5px;
}
.mobile-square {
 width: 49%;
 height: auto;
 min-height: 95px;
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #008fc5;
 text-align:center;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 border-radius: 5px;
 position:relative;
}
.mobile-square p {
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.active {
 background-color: #004762;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/670a0bbb85.js"></script>
 <div class="mobile-container">
  <div class="mobile-row">
   <a href="#fa">
   <div class="mobile-square">
    <i class="fa fa-globe" style="font-size:48px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p>
     Foreign Affairs
    </p>
   </div>
   </a>
   <a href="#travel">
   <div class="mobile-square">
    <i class="fa fa-plane" style="font-size:48px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p>
     Travel
    </p>
   </div>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="mobile-container">
  <div class="mobile-row">
   <a href="#dev">
   <div class="mobile-square">
    <i class="fa fa-code" style="font-size:48px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p>
     Development
    </p>
   </div>
   </a>
   <a href="#misc">
   <div class="mobile-square">
    <i class="fa fa-heart" style="font-size:48px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p>
     Fitness
    </p>
   </div>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better off using toggle instead of show/hide. Take a look to see if this points you in the right direction.

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/c3md14jf/1/`
```